# Arm joint Mesh not moving with Chest mesh when animating

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

Im currently animating a run cycle for my mech and it seems that the arm joint mesh doesn't want to move with the Chest mesh. I had the mesh joined to the chest mesh. Is there something im missing?

blend file 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch your armature to *Pose* mode then your mesh to *Weight Paint* mode you'll see that the chest bone has zero influence on the arm joints. If you join a mesh to another one Blender can't guess what group the new mesh vertices are supposed to be part of. So use a weight paint brush or assign these vertices to the chest group.

Comment: So in order to fix this i have to scrap the animation and weight paint it correctly in order to have it working properly?

Comment: you don't have to scrap the animation, just paint the arms in Weight Paint mode